# Zend Studio formatter uses wrong format

Tags: php, zend-studio, formatter

I am using [ibuildings ZF](http://blog.hackix.com/2010/03/zend-studio-code-formatter-for-zend-framework/). When I press Ctr+Shift+F
the code is formated this way

```
$adapter = $this->getAuthAdapter(
$form->getValues());
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);
if (! $result->isValid()) {
    $form->setDescription(
    'Invalid credentials provided');
    $this->view->form = $form;
    return $this->render('index');
}
```

but I want to be formatted that way

```
$adapter = $this->getAuthAdapter($form->getValues());
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);
if (! $result->isValid()) {
    $form->setDescription('Invalid input');
    $this->view->form = $form;
    return $this->render('index');
}
```

how to configure this?

Answer (score 1):

The formatter can be configured in Window > Preferences > PHP > Code Style > Formatter > Edit... > Line Wrapping .

All the Settings are choose 'Do not wrap'.