# Format PHP code in Zend Studio

Tags: php, zend-framework, code-formatting

I am using zend studio IDE to write code.

I use code formatter to format my code. Most of code is formatted by code formatter but not all.

What I want,

```
$is_admin = $this->logged_user->isAdmin();
```

should format in same way like

```
$is_admin = $this->logged_user->isAdmin();
```

not like

```
$is_admin = $this->logged_user
                 ->isAdmin();
```

Any idea?

Comment: Already answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455869/php-zend-studio-formatter-problem

Answer (score 0):

Zend Studio 11.0

Window -> Preferences -> PHP -> Code Style -> Formatter -> (button) Edit -> (tab) New Lines:

Insert new line after method invocation, when chaining at least: 0

Wilwor ;)